# What steps should I take if I haven't received responses from potential supervisors?

Tags: graduate-admissions, supervision, new-zealand

I am in the process of applying for the M.Sc. Research program at universities in New Zealand. My application will not be assessed unless I secure a supervisor. Despite reaching out to three potential supervisors, I have not received any responses. Do universities in New Zealand typically offer assistance to students in finding a supervisor for their research programs? Any guidance in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: How long have you waited for a response?

Comment: I have waited for 2 weeks

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't heard in a couple of weeks you can follow up with a request for information. Ask whether there is any more information they would like or need.

As for getting help, let me suggest that you write to the department head and ask for help in finding a supervisor. Mention your general field, and subfield if possible, but you don't need to send everything you'd send to a potential supervisor. Perhaps they can point someone to you.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.